# How to get cart line items in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need help in getting all items that are added in cart.
I’m actually showing count of each product that’s added in cart.
I’ve tried current_order but it’s acting weird, sometimes it’s correct but sometimes even if cart is empty it shows the product in current_order so it’s breaking if the cart updates.
Can you guys please recommend me a way to get the cart items directly?

Updated

In View

```
<% count = count_in_cart(simple_current_order, product) %>
<span class="badge badge-notify rounded-bottom"><%=count%></span>
```

In Application Helper

```
def count_in_cart(current_order, product)
  return 0 unless current_order
  product = current_order.line_items.select{|item| item.variant_id ==product.id}.last
  product.present? ? product.quantity : 0
end
```

It works like a charm in local, but on heroku it doesn't show the count.
Can someone please guide what I'm doing wrong?

Spree version is 3.7.2

Comment: Please give in more details.
Are you using spree?
Is the issue happening in server side or client side?
If so please add the code snippet that you are trying to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the things were behaving weird in view files due to maybe objects stored in memory.

I managed to fix it by creating a new API and calculating the products in that Controller.

```
@cart_items_order = simple_current_order if simple_current_order.present?
render json: @cart_items_order&.line_items
```

That worked like a charm.

For anyone who looks for this thing in future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your count_in_cart function. The function that you have written gets the quantity of the last line_item, however what you actually want is to count per product.

```
def count_in_cart(current_order, product)
  current_order.where(product: product).to_a.sum(&:quantity)
end
```

Comment: It works with both current_order and simple_current_order on local environment,
but doesn't seems to work on heroku. :facepalm:
@Surya

Comment: Please add these  details in the question as well.
What version of spree are you using.
The code snippets that you are trying to use with loggers and their output.

Comment: I just updated the question, please see if it's enough explanation.

Comment: No, actually I'm not getting the last line_item
`
select{|item| item.variant_id ==product.id}
`
it's selecting the corresponding item which matches with the product id.

Comment: Try this in your function `current_order.where(product: product).to_a.sum(&:quantity)`

Comment: It says ```undefined method `where' for #<Spree::Order:0x00007f87f94a5b18>```

Comment: Try for line items  `current_order.line_items.where(product: product).to_a.sum(&:quantity)`